# gcc inline x86 asm code producing garbage results

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

This program takes two input integers and produces x^y and prints in the main; the actual computation is inline x86 asm (at&t). Can any of you say why garbage is getting loaded in the registers and junk printed? Any help is appreciated. i used gcc -m32 compile options

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

short power(short x, short y)
{
    short z;

    __asm__ __volatile__(
    "pusha \n"
    "mov    %[x], %%eax \n"         //x argument
    "mov    %[y], %%ebx \n"         //y argument
    "mov     %%eax, %%ecx\n"
    "mul_loop:\n"
    "imul   %%ecx, %%eax \n"        //loop multiply x by x until y goes to 0
    "dec    %%ebx\n"
    "jnz    mul_loop\n"
    "mov    %%eax, %[z] \n"
    "popa \n"
    :[z] "=m" (z)
    :[x] "m" (x), [y] "m" (y)
    : "eax", "ebx", "ecx"
    );
    return z;
}

int main (void)
{
    short x, y, res =0;
    char line[32];


    printf("enter numbers \n");

    fgets (line, sizeof(line), stdin);

    x = (short) atoi (strtok(line, " "));
    y = (short) atoi (strtok(NULL, " "));

    res = power(x, y);
    printf ("%d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `short` is 16 bit but you use 32. Change `short` to `int` unless you have a good reason not to. Also you have an off-by-one error, your loop runs one too many times. Note that `x ^ y` needs `y - 1` multiplications.

Comment: Also, why write this in inline asm? Is this a class project?  Inline asm is the hardest way to learn about asm.  And if performance matters, this can be written without pusha/popa and 3 `mov` instructions can be omitted with minor changes.

Comment: You don't need pusha/popa, just declare clobbers on any registers you want to hard-code (or use dummy register outputs to let the compiler pick registers).  If GCC uses addressing modes relative to ESP, your `pusha` will break them.  So even after fixing this, your code will break with `gcc -O1` or higher, which enables `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Comment: ouch ... Jester is right! thx David and Peter for positive feedback.